# ThreadPoolExecutor hangs when call futur result in a futur callback

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-requests, concurrent.futures

I am using "[requests-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures)" package and call asynchronous get/post in asynchronous get/post result callback (add_done_callback on futur result). Sometimes, my code hangs. After many investigation hours, I can reproduce the lock with a minimal code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)

def f(_):
    time.sleep(0.1) # Try to force context switch
    x = pool.submit(lambda: None)
    print "1"
    x.result()
    print "2"

def main():
    x = pool.submit(lambda : None)
    x.add_done_callback(f)
    print "3"
    x.result()
    print "4"

print "==="
main()
```

If I run this peace of code in a bash loop:

```
$> while true; do python code.py; done;
```

The program hangs every times with the "trace":

```
(...)
===
1
2
3
4
===
3
4
1
```

If I break it with ctrl^c, I have the following stack trace:

```
^CError in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/home/yienyien/Angus/test/futur/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 46, in _python_exit
    t.join(sys.maxint)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 951, in join
    self.__block.wait(delay)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 359, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
KeyboardInterrupt
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/home/yienyien/Angus/test/futur/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 46, in _python_exit
    t.join(sys.maxint)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 951, in join
    self.__block.wait(delay)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 359, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Somebody could explain me what is happening ? I check [the possible deadlocks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) in the concurrent.futures module, but I do not think it matches.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I answer to my own question. 
After investigation, it's simple. I do not shutdown the `TheadPoolExecutor` and do not use `with`, then sometimes the `main` function completes and the finalize the main thread, the `ThreadPoolExecutor` state becomes "shutdown" whereas callback is not completed.

Answer (score 1):

tasks submitted to a fixed-sized thread pool may not call blocking operations like `Future.result()`. This leads to a specific kind of deadlock, called "thread starvation". Using `time.sleep()` also switches a thread off the service and increases probability of thread starvation.

Comment: I do not think this is the case, but I found, it's much simpler. I will write the answer. Thank you.